# this value in JavaScript anonymous function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, anonymous-function

Can anybody explain to me why `A` is true and `B` is false? I would have expected B to be true as well.

```
function MyObject() {

};

MyObject.prototype.test = function () {
    console.log("A", this instanceof MyObject);
    (function () {
        console.log("B", this instanceof MyObject);
    }());
}

new MyObject().test();
```

update:
since ecmascript-6 you can use arrow functions which would make it easy to refer to MyObject like this:

```
function MyObject() {

};

MyObject.prototype.test = function () {
    console.log("A", this instanceof MyObject);
    (() => {//a change is here, which will have the effect of the next line resulting in true
        console.log("B", this instanceof MyObject);
    })(); //and here is a change
}

new MyObject().test();
```

Comment: Welcome to functional scope in JavaScript.

Comment: @zzzzBov: That's not a closure.

Comment: You might want to use an additional pair of parens to improve readability: `( new MyObject() ).test()`

Comment: @SLaks, I've edited my comment to correctly reflect the usage of the anonymous function, although it *is* being used as a closure.

Comment: No; it's not being used as a closure.  It's not closing over anything.  Scope is not really relevant.

Comment: @zzzzBov Correct me if I'm wrong, but IIFE's can't form closures since they're invoked immediately. Only when a function survives (as a reference) the invocation of its outer function, only then we have a closure.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Wrong; using a variable in an IIFE still creates a closure. Even though it probably won't last beyond the parent scope, it's still a closure.  Also, the IIFE could cause itself to be called later if it's named.

Comment: @SLaks Assuming that it's a anonymous IIFE, that it doesn't declare any local variables, and that it doesn't contain any nested function declarations/expressions, would it be a closure in that case? (hypothetically speaking, unrelated to this question)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: If it doesn't actually use any parent variables and doesn't call `eval`, it isn't a closure.

Comment: @SLaks Ah yes, of course. If the function uses its scope chain (if it accesses any of its outer scopes), then it's a closure.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, SLaks, could one of you provide a third party definition of "closure" that you feel acceptably describes closures in JavaScript?

Comment: @zzzzBov I'm working on it in the [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17) `:)`

Comment: @zzzzBov: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/111200/21475)

Comment: @Cameron, so what's the definition? closures don't need to be returned from some function in order to retain a reference to it outside of its original functional scope. My definition of a closure is **"any block that *closes* (retains, remembers, stores reference to, etc) over the variables previously in scope, and allows for instantiation of new variables without polluting the parent's scope"**. I'm sure it's a naive definition, but it's a start.

Comment: @Cameron, [this answer states that all functions are closures in JS](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/40454/what-is-a-closure).

Comment: @zzzzBov: That's a good definition.  However, instead of "previously in scope", I would say "from a parent scope".

Comment: @zzzzBov: Right, they don't need to be returned, but the key is that a function isn't (technically) a closure until it leaves its parent's scope (and, of course, references variables in its parent's scope).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`this` is special. It refers to the object that the function is being called on behalf of (most commonly via dot syntax).

So, in the case of `A`, the function is being called on behalf of a new `MyObject` object. `B` is in a different function that isn't explicitly being called on behalf of any object, so `this` defaults to the global object (`window`).

In other words, `this` changes depending on how the function is *called*, not where or how it is defined. The fact that you're using an anonymous function (defined inside another function) is coincidental and has no effect on the value of `this`.

Comment: Your statement "`this` changes depending on how the function is *called*, not where or how it is defined", can be misleading. In fact, `this` is simply the called function's owner - and that is in itself always either is explicitly defined or defaults to the global object. `myVar.doSomething = doSomething;` defines the function `myVar.doSomething` as `doSomething` where `this` will always refer to `myVar` when calling `myVar.doSomething()`, regardless of where `myVar.doSomething()` is called from. Your statement might suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 40):

Inside of your anonymous function `this` is the global object.

Inside of `test`, this is the instance of `MyObject` on which the method was invoked.

---

Whenever you call a function like this:

```
someFunction(); // called function invocation
```

`this` is **always** the global object, or `undefined` in strict mode (unless `someFunction` was created with `bind`<sup>**</sup> — see below)

Whenever you call a function like this

```
foo.someMethod();  //called method invocation
```

`this` is set to `foo`

---

<sup>**</sup>EcmaScript5 defines a `bind` function that allows you to create a function that has a pre-set value for `this`

So this

```
    var obj = { a: 12 };
    var someFunction = (function () { alert(this.a); }).bind(obj);
    someFunction();
```

Causes `someFucntion` to be invoked with `this` equal to `obj`, and alerts 12.  I bring this up only to note that this is a potential exception to the rule I mentioned about functions invoked as

```
someFunction();
```

always having `this` equal to the global object (or `undefined` in strict mode)

Comment: The line `(function () { alert(this.a); }).bind(obj)` is exactly what I was looking for - binding context to an anonymous function. Works perfectly, +1

Comment: you can also set the `this` using `func.call(this, arg1, arg2..)`

Answer (score 11):

In the anonymous function, `this` is bound to the global object (`window` in a browser environment).

There are various ways of accessing the instance:

```
var self = this;
(function () {
    console.log("B", self instanceof MyObject);
}());
```

or

```
(function () {
    console.log("B", this instanceof MyObject);
}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 4):

`this` is set based on how you call the function.
Your anonymous function is a normal function call, so `this` is the global object.

You could write `(function() { ... }).call(this)` to explicitly call it with your `this`.

Comment: Well, I'm assuming strict mode, so... `:)`

Comment: ... so `this` is `undefined`.