# Newbie: Javascript constructor and scope-context issue

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm confused as to what the problem is with context in a JS constructor. Within the ctor I have a function declared. Before the call to that function `this` is set to the context of the ctor. Inside the function the value of `this` is set to `window`. I don't understand why. In the HTML the ctor is called with 'new'.

```
function MyCtor() {
    var myFunc = function() {
         debugger; // #2
         // code for myFunc
     }

     debugger;  // #1
     myFunc();
     debugger;  // #3
}
```

At debugger #1, `this` is set to `MyCtor`. At #2 `this` is `window`. And at #3 it is back to `MyCtor`.

I'm sure I'm missing something basic here, but I've read a lot on scope and context; obviously not enough.

Comment: Read about functions and scope here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Comment: …and about the [`this` keyword ("context") here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). It should never have been set to `MyCtor`, unless you're calling the constructor in weird ways.

Comment: @Bergi when we call MyCtor with new, what will the 'this' be displayed inside the body?

Comment: @grape_mao: The new instance (an object inheriting from `MyCtor.prototype`). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_a_constructor

Comment: @Bergi sure, but in the console it shows somwthing like 'MyCtor{}'. Maybe that's why OP says this is set to MyCtor.

Comment: @grape_mao: Yeah, the console might display it as "object constructed by MyCtor". Yet when expanding its properties you should notice that it's not the `MyCtor` function :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` object is one of the most annoyingly hard-to-understand concepts in Javascript. And that's quite a contest to win... First off, you have to understand that it will be specific to each function you call - the context in which you call myFunc won't set it how you want it. Here's one way you can do it:

```
function MyCtor() {
    this.myFunc = function() {
         debugger; // #2
         // code for myFunc
     }

     debugger;  // #1
     this.myFunc();
     debugger;  // #3
}
```

Generally, there are only a few situations in which you can rely upon a function's `this` to be a particular value. All of them to my knowledge:

```
objectToBeThis.aFunction = function() { ... } // declare this function as
// an object property at any time - 
objectToBeThis.aFunction();
```

Or, not used as often is:

```
aFunction.call(objectToBeThis, extraArgument1, extraArgument2);
```

When a named, but not "owned" function (ie, `var functionName = function()`, or `function functionName()`) is called, then it will have `window` as its `this` argument. This part I'm less sure of as a certainty, but I just wouldn't use `this` inside such a method.

As in the case of your code, there's also "new MyCtor" - in which a new object is created to be returned, and that object is set to `this` inside of the constructor method.

Comment: Still a bit confused here. Does this mean that via hoisting, all 'var' declarations really belong to 'window'? I would think that that would lead to name collisions. If `myFunc` is declared within the constructor using 'var', why isn't it bound to `MyCtor`?

Comment: Found additional info in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670877/this-value-in-javascript-anonymous-function)

Comment: Anything that belongs to 'window' is a global. Any function arguments, or variables declared inside of a function, are local variables accessible to that function, as well as any functions declared inside that function (closures). `var`s don't really "belong" to any object, and as such, you don't use the dot syntax for them. This also means you can't access a `var` outside of the function it was declared in. Hope that helps; it's definitely confusing.