# `This` in nested function is global object

Tags: javascript, object, nested-function

Can someone explain the concept behind this ?

assume we have a function as a method of an object:

```
var myobj = {
    myfunc : function () {      
        console.log(this); // Logs reference to myobj.                            
    }
};
myobj.myfunc();
```

while a nested function inside the same function `myfunc` will return reference to head object ( window ) :

```
var myobj = {
    myfunc : function () {      
       ( function (){
           console.log(this); // Logs reference to head window object.   
       })();                     
    } 
 };
myobj.myfunc();
```

It really confuses me how this works, as i thought function will always return reference to the parent object.

The question is, is this a fixed rule, that is any nested function will always rreturn reference to `window` ?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670877/this-value-in-javascript-anonymous-function

Comment: your inner function is a closure, so  "this" would always point to the window object.you have to save "this" on a temp variable before accessing it inside the anonymous function.

Comment: this might be a useful post for anyone who looks for deeper explaination : http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/ , thanks to adeneo for the searching key IIFE.

Comment: Would you please post your code with usable indentation?

Comment: @Bergi guess you have the privilge to edit my code , go ahead and fix it if you want , you are welcome.

Comment: @ProllyGeek: Yes, I have the *privilege* to edit it, but you as the poster have the *duty* to put readable code in your questions - it helps to get good answers and upvotes.

Comment: @Bergi ok done , let me know if it requires further modifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that the correct answer is like following (after 2 hours of searching) , this book ["JavaScript Succinctly"](https://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/ebooks/javascript) states that:

> You might be wondering what happens to this when it is used inside of
>   a function that is contained inside of another function. The bad news
>   is in ECMA 3, this loses its way and refers to the head object (the
>   window object in browsers), instead of the object within which the
>   function is defined.

it also states that:

> The good news is that this will be fixed in ECMAScript 5. For now, you
>   should be aware of this predicament, especially when you start passing
>   functions around as values to other functions.

so simply the answer is YES, any nested function will always return head object as reference.

Also you can use a work-around to solve this issue, by storing the value of `this` as soon as it is available, like following:

```
var myObject = {  
    myProperty: 'I can see the light', 
    myMethod : function() {
        var that = this; // Store a reference to this (i.e. myObject) in myMethod scope.
        var helperFunction = function() { // Child function.    // Logs 'I can see the light' via scope chain because that = this.
            console.log(that.myProperty); // Logs 'I can see the light'.
            console.log(this); // Logs window object, if we don't use "that".
        }(); 
    }
};  
myObject.myMethod(); // Invoke myMethod.
```

Answer (score 4):

The value of `this` inside a function depends on how it's called, not how it's defined

When you call the function in the scope of `myobj`, `myobj` will be the value of `this`

```
myobj.myfunc();
```

When you call a function with no execution context, the value of this will be the global object, in this case `window`.

```
function test() {

    console.log(this); // window

}

test(); // global context
```

when you create an IIFE, the execution context is the window as no other context is set

```
( function (){
    console.log(this); // window
})();
```

Then there's `apply`, `call` and `bind` which would let you set another value of `this` for the called function.

Comment: Actually i know this already , but my question is clear , it is all about nested functions , will any nested function return reference to head object ?

Comment: It's not about nested functions, how the function is defined is not what's important, it's how it's called. An IIFE is called right away with no special context, so it uses the global context, hence `this` inside the function is the window.

Comment: IIFE umm , after searching i got it , thanks for the expression.

Comment: No problem, just try to remember that it's not how you define the function, but how you call it that matters, and if it's called with no context, it will always use the global context (window). Once you get that, it's a lot easier to grok.

Comment: please check my own answer.

Comment: Whatever floats your goat !