# Javascript: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, removechild

i am trying to recreate a some practices from one of the courses. Its about to remove a li-item from an UL and append it to another UL.

When i write my code in the following way all works finde

```
var removeMeandAppendMe = function() {
    var parentLi = this.parentNode;
    var goneElement = incompleList.removeChild(parentLi);
    compleList.appendChild(goneElement);
};

var li = incompleList.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var i = 0; i < incompleList.children.length; i++) {
    var link = li[i];
    var liCheckArray = link.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var liCheck = liCheckArray[0];
    liCheck.onchange = removeMeandAppendMe;
}
```

When i change my code to the following i get the error "Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'".

```
function removeMeandAppendMe(fromList, toList) {
    var parentLi = this.parentNode;
    var goneElement = fromList.removeChild(parentLi);
    toList.appendChild(goneElement);
}

var li = incompleList.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var i = 0; i < incompleList.children.length; i++) {
    var link = li[i];
    var liCheckArray = link.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var liCheck = liCheckArray[0];
    liCheck.onchange = removeMeandAppendMe(incompleList, compleList);
}
```

What bothers me, is the fact that the code runs well when my removeMeandAppendMe-function is without parameters and doesnt work with parameters. Can anyone tell my why and where my mistake is? Thank you.

(I'm aware of the blur-problem discussed here: [Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926083/failed-to-execute-removechild-on-node))

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing your problem?

Comment: what is `incompleteList`?  Where is it assigned?

Comment: Sure: http://jsfiddle.net/9uj7zfoL/

Comment: `incompleteList` and `compleList` are the ids of the both unordered lists

Comment: The problem is on the last line. You aren't assigning `removeMeandAppendMe`, you are invoking it. I would suggest looking into the `.bind()` function to achieve what you're looking to do.

Comment: but how can i assign a function with parameters without invoking it?

Comment: @Steve by wrapping it in an anonymous function.

Comment: @Pointy: That didnt work, I added `var anonFunction = function() {
        removeMeandAppendMe(incompleList, compleList);
    };` outside the loop and assigned it to the onchange.Eventhandler

Comment: @Steve ah, right; well now you're running into the "assign an event handler in a loop" problem.

Comment: @Pointy: well that might be, but it doesnt explain why the first codeblock runs and the second doesnt. after all we have "assign an event handler in a loop" problem in both blocks.

Answer (score 0):

First, as Pointy mentioned, you do need to wrap your call to `RemoveMeandAppendMe(incompleList, compleList)` in an anonymous function so that it is not invoked prematurely.

Taking that into account, you are receiving this error because of what the value of `this` is the case of each function invocation. When calling `RemoveMeandAppendMe()`, `this` is an HTMLInputElement object, but when calling `RemoveMeandAppendMe(incompleList, compleList)`, `this` is the Window object, and so `this.parentNode` is `undefined` (and thus "not of type 'Node'", which is why you're seeing that error message).

There are a lot of subtleties to this question: what `this` refers to, and also how different 'function' declarations are treated (lots of discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-function-declaration-syntax-var-fn-function-vs-function-fn?rq=1)). Just changing the way `RemoveMeandAppendMe(incompleList, compleList)` is declared doesn't resolve the issue either.

In a way, your question boils down to "Why does `this` refer to the Window object for the parameterized function call, but an HTMLInputElement object for the non-parameterized function call?" I believe that in this case, this is because, when we wrap the invocation of the parameterized function call in an anonymous function (like so: `liCheck.onchange = function(){removeMeandAppendMe(incompleList, compleList);};`), `removeMeandAppendMe` has no 'local' owner, so the ownership of this function defaults to the global object, Window ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670877/this-value-in-javascript-anonymous-function)).

To fix this, you can pass in `this` to the invocation of `removeMeandAppendMe`, where `this` will refer to the checkbox, and then use it as a variable within that parameterized function. I've put all of this in your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9uj7zfoL/3/) where things can be played with by commenting/uncommenting different things. Hope this helped.