# Failed to execute removeChild on Node

Tags: javascript

Other stack answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926083/failed-to-execute-removechild-on-node) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278307/javascript-failed-to-execute-removechild-on-node-parameter-1-is-not-of-typ) seem to be specialized cases and I believe my case is more generalized. I am doing this in my js:

```
var markerDiv = document.createElement("div");
markerDiv.innerHTML = "<div id='MyCoolDiv' style='color: #2b0808'>123</div>";
document.getElementById("playerContainer").appendChild(markerDiv);

// after a brief delay, REMOVE the appended child
setTimeout(function(){ 
    var myCoolDiv = document.getElementById("MyCoolDiv");
    document.getElementById("playerContainer").removeChild(myCoolDiv);
}, 1500);
```

Everything works correctly and as expected (the div is correctly appended and I can see it) until `removeChild()` is called, at which time I get the error `Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node'`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your `myCoolDiv` element isn't a child of the player container. It's a child of the `div` you created as a wrapper for it (`markerDiv` in the first part of the code). Which is why it fails, `removeChild` only removes children, not descendants.

You'd want to remove that wrapper div, or not add it at all.

Here's the "not adding it at all" option:

```js
var markerDiv = document.createElement("div");
markerDiv.innerHTML = "<div id='MyCoolDiv' style='color: #2b0808'>123</div>";
document.getElementById("playerContainer").appendChild(markerDiv.firstChild);
// -------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^

setTimeout(function(){ 
    var myCoolDiv = document.getElementById("MyCoolDiv");
    document.getElementById("playerContainer").removeChild(myCoolDiv);
}, 1500);
```

```html
<div id="playerContainer"></div>
```

Or without using the wrapper (although it's quite handy for parsing that HTML):

```js
var myCoolDiv = document.createElement("div");
// Don't reall need this: myCoolDiv.id = "MyCoolDiv";
myCoolDiv.style.color = "#2b0808";
myCoolDiv.appendChild(
  document.createTextNode("123")
);
document.getElementById("playerContainer").appendChild(myCoolDiv);

setTimeout(function(){ 
    // No need for this, we already have it from the above:
    // var myCoolDiv = document.getElementById("MyCoolDiv");
    document.getElementById("playerContainer").removeChild(myCoolDiv);
}, 1500);
```

```html
<div id="playerContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 26):

For me, a hint to wrap the troubled element in another HTML tag helped. However I also needed to add a key to that HTML tag. For example:

```
// Didn't work
<div>
     <TroubledComponent/>
</div>

// Worked
<div key='uniqueKey'>
     <TroubledComponent/>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised adding a key was all that was needed! Brilliant!

Comment: cool, this worked for me, but can you explain why its needed :)

Comment: I had a component `LoginCheck`, which caused the issue, simply wrapping it in a `<div>` in the *parent* component removed the error for me. I didn't need a `key`. But thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: simply adding a `key` with a mundane value as in `key={0}` worked like a charm in my case. In my particular case I think the offending library was `ag-grid` for React. In the end, the code that worked was: `return <span key={0}><i className="fas fa-check"></i></span>;`.

Answer (score 8):

I was wraped it with  <> </> as a parent  when I changed it to normal , div , its worked fine

Comment: This is the second time I run into this issue. Thx for sharing, works perfectly!

Comment: fragments are a react thing, this question isn't using react

Answer (score 6):

The direct parent of your child is markerDiv, so you should call remove from markerDiv as so:

```
markerDiv.removeChild(myCoolDiv);
```

Alternatively, you may want to remove markerNode. Since that node was appended directly to videoContainer, it can be removed with:

```
document.getElementById("playerContainer").removeChild(markerDiv);
```

Now, the easiest general way to remove a node, if you are absolutely confident that you did insert it into the DOM, is this:

```
markerDiv.parentNode.removeChild(markerDiv);
```

This works for any node (just replace markerDiv with a different node), and finds the parent of the node directly in order to call remove from it. If you are unsure if you added it, double check if the parentNode is non-null before calling removeChild.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, `myCoolDiv` is a child of `markerDiv` not `playerContainer`. If you want to remove `myCoolDiv` but keep `markerDiv` for some reason you can do the following

```
myCoolDiv.parentNode.removeChild(myCoolDiv);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3a0oLLs/)

Answer (score 2):

In next.js 13, if you are using app directory and forget to put `<html>` and `<body>` open close tags in `app/layout.tsx` file you might see this error as well.

Comment: thanks, i have a real problem with this thing. Using <providers> 2 times

Answer (score 1):

I'd a similar problem in the `vue.js` project. Then, I got a hint on changing the `fragment` wrapper to an HTML element. The most common use case for fragments is probably when you need to return multiple elements. With fragments this is easy and you don't need your typical wrapper div for the elements. Its short syntax is `<></>`.

Basically, I used the fragment pattern in `Vue` then I got the above error rendering the component dynamically using `transition`. It appears that the dynamic component(which entails multiple elements) needed to be wrapped with an HTML element, not a fragment.

```
// Vuejs
<transition
  name="router-anim"
  enter-active-class="animated animated-enter"
  mode="out-in"
  leave-active-class="animated animated-exit"
>
  <router-view /> // dynamic rendering based on current route using vue-router
</transition>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not duplicating elements in single file .For example: you have page-one.js which has `<body> </body>` element in it and you imported a component named component-one.js which also has `<body> </body>` in it. This will produce the error you are asking for. This applies to all main elements : `<header>, <main>, <footer>, <body>, <html>` . Make sure these elements are not duplicating after getting components imported. Child elements like `<div>` and others donot give these errors.