# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript

I just noticed an issue with my chat extension for phpBB. I've had some recent memory issues and just can't get it figured out. If someone could lend a hand it would be greatly appreciated

the js with an issue...

```
            } else if (type == 'delete') {
            var parent = document.getElementById('chat');
            var child = document.getElementById('p' + results[0]);
            parent.removeChild(child);
        }
```

if anyone needs to see the full js. just ask and i will post it

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956884/failed-to-execute-removechild-on-node

Comment: the solution that helped HerrimanCoder does not work in my case so i don'tt see it as a duplicate. similar maybe but not the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check if the `child` exists before removal:

```
} else if (type == 'delete') {
  var parent = document.getElementById('chat');
  var child = parent.getElementById('p' + results[0]);
  if (child) parent.removeChild(child);
}
```

Comment: i'm accepting your post as the answer. however, the only line i changed to make it work without error is the last line `if (child) parent.removeChild(child);`. thank you very much

Comment: @Darin, yes, that line removes the error. Another one `var child = parent.getElementById('p' + results[0]);` searches the child within the parent, not within whole document. This improves the performance and may be optional.

Answer (score 0):

[removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=removeChild) is a method of [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node), this is what the error message tells you with

> 'removeChild' of 'Node'

the first parameter is `child` and the error message tells you that it's not a `Node`.

[getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) returns the element having that id if exists. If not, the `null` is returned. `Node` is the parent interface of [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).

Since it's not a Node, it is null. Hence `child` does not exist.

Comment: thank you for your explanation but it was not helpful at all. like i said in my post, i've had some recent memory issues and i do use google first before asking for help. i had already read what you posted but am unable to understand it since my memory issues happened. what Kosh posted helped me solve the issue or at least stop the error completely without any loss of function