# TestCafe throws this when clicking popup buttons Error: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node

Tags: testcafe, outsystems

I'm new to testcafe and I getting this error when trying to click any buttons on a popup - I'm not doing anything fancy (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956884/failed-to-execute-removechild-on-node), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926083/failed-to-execute-removechild-on-node) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278307/javascript-failed-to-execute-removechild-on-node-parameter-1-is-not-of-typ)):

```
A JavaScript error occurred on

   "https://*tst.outsystems*/*Popup.aspx?LoanRequestId=0&DepartmentId=7&*".
      Repeat test actions in the browser and check the console for errors.
      To ignore client-side JavaScript errors, enable the "--skip-js-errors" CLI option, or set the "skipJsErrors" configuration file property      
      to "true".

      JavaScript error details:
      Error: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
          at t._removeNodeCore (hammerhead.js:10:29496)
          at HTMLBodyElement.removeChild (hammerhead.js:11:553)
          at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>
      (https://*tst.outsystems*/Loan/Blocks/RichWidgets/jQueryUI/jQueryUIInternal.en.js?11602:7:3589)
          at l (https://*tst.outsystems*/Loan/_osjs.js?11_14_1_34445:19:17956)
          at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://*tst.outsystems*/Loan/_osjs.js?11_14_1_34445:19:18736)
          at Function.ready (https://*tst.outsystems*/Loan/_osjs.js?11_14_1_34445:19:13154)
          at HTMLDocument.mb (https://*tst.outsystems*/Loan/_osjs.js?11_14_1_34445:19:10522)
```

I don't get errors in console if I'm doing the same thing manually and I would prefer to know if there are any client-side JS errors.

I'd recently installed NodeJS 16.15.0 on my work (windows) laptop; I'm testing an application written using Outsystems technologies.

My testcafe code looks like this:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Getting Started`
    .page `https://*tst.outsystems*`;

const buttonClose = Selector('.MainPopup [value="Close"]')


test('1. Login w. front office', async t => {
/* login and some navigation code... everything, from here, works*/
  await t.click(buttonClose)
});
```

Comment: To ignore client-side JavaScript errors, enable the "--skip-js-errors" CLI option, or set the "skipJsErrors" configuration file property to "true".

Comment: @AlexSkorkin Thank you. Are these client-side js errors?

Comment: There may be client-side js errors. It's difficult to analyze this issue without an example app. Try using this option and check if it works.
If it doesn't, please create a simple sample following this instruction: https://testcafe.io/402636/faq#how-to-create-a-minimal-working-example-when-you-submit-an-issue. And share your result according to the following template: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml