# React/Firebase - unable to call this.props from within auth function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a login function to that authenticates with Firebase and then should call a login function passed down from a parent as props. Here it is:

```
class HeaderParentComponent extends Component { 
    toggleSignupLayoverAction(event){
        this.props.toggleSignupLayover("true")
    }
    signIn(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var email = $(".login-email").val();
        var password = $(".login-user-password").val();

        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user) {  
            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            this.props.logUserIn(user);
        }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
        });

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="header-inner">
                <span onClick={this.props.toggleMenuOut} className="menuToggle"></span>
                <a className="logo-a-tag" href="#">
                    <img height="25" src="../../images/logo.png" alt="my logo"/>
                </a>
                <form className="header-searchbox">
                    <input placeholder="Search Samples Here..." onChange={this.props.updateSearch} value={this.props.searchInputVal} type="text"></input>
                </form>
                <div className="header-acc"><a className={"login " + this.props.loggedInState} href="#">Login</a><a onClick={this.toggleSignupLayoverAction.bind(this)} className={"create " + this.props.loggedInState} href="#">Create Account</a>
                <div className={"logged-in-header " + this.props.loggedInState}>Hello {this.props.LoggedInUsername}</div>
                </div>
                <div className="login-popup-par">
                    <form>
                        <input placeholder="Email Address" className="login-email" type="text"></input>
                        <input placeholder="Password" className="login-user-password" type="password"></input>
                        <button onClick={this.signIn.bind(this)}>Login</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            )
        }
}
```

The props that has been passed down from the parent for the moment has a basic console.log of "logged in". It is passed down through the `this.props.logUserIn(user);` props. The issue is im trying to call this after authentication with Firebase has succeeded hence why I but it in a .then function after the `.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` It seems that I can't call `this.props.logUserIn` from inside the Auth function but I have no idea why. If I move the props function to outside the auth function it will call it no problem. Why can't I access the props from in there?

Comment: Use an arrow function

Comment: Care to elaborate Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `this` in the anonymous function in `then(function)`  [by default refers to the `window` object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8670877/5647260). You're effectively trying to do `window.props.logUserIn(user)` which is obviously not desired.

To combat this you may use ES6 [arrow functions](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjPv_CV6P3PAhWi3YMKHbNAAi0QFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FFunctions%2FArrow_functions&usg=AFQjCNGCR-aBleRFoozNm96tBHjzBNB9Aw) that do not bind `this` and refers to that of the enclosing context, the component. With arrow functions, `this` will not be `window`, but the component and will execute the method properly:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((user) => {  
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    this.props.logUserIn(user);
}).catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
});
```

A pre-ES6 way to do this is to use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) on regular functions to explicitly bind `this` context and other arguments to the function. Here's an example:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user) {  
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    this.props.logUserIn(user);
}.bind(this));
//...
```

This works because `this` outside the anonymous function is the component, and the context is passed to the function.

---

You need a `constructor`which is called on class instantiation, and is needed to use `props`. See [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#constructor), use:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    /*this.state = { //for state if needed

    };*/
}  

//...

signIn(e) {
   //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, makes sense now why the props wern't being referred to. I've converted another function here to arrows but its not working this time. Instead im now getting a console error TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined(…). Here's the code here https://jsfiddle.net/8qL3fqj3/1/ would be amazing if you could take a look

Comment: hey @Andrew Here's the fiddle with all the JSX. Will upvote if you can help me solve it for sure! https://jsfiddle.net/8qL3fqj3/2/

Comment: @BenLiger You need a constructor method

Comment: ive heard of constructors but no too familiar with how they work. Are they easy to implement?

Comment: @BenLiger Yes. It's just a method of the class. They construct the class and pass props. See the updated answer

Comment: i've implemented it here but its giving me console errors https://jsfiddle.net/vwyfrgj4/1/ . Sorry this is a bit confusing!

Comment: @BenLiger What errors? You should have the constructor as the first method per convention

Comment: SignupComponent.js:85 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Comment: which is the line this.props.logUserIn(sendUserId);

Comment: @BenLiger Did you trying using `bind`?

Comment: yes as you can see in https://jsfiddle.net/vwyfrgj4/1/ it uses .bind in all onClicks

Comment: @BenLiger You've got an arrow function inside a regular function. Check your `updateProfile` promise.

Comment: That was it! Thanks Andrew