# How to use Vue Concurrency inside Pinia? TypeScript error: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation. ts(2683)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I have a Vue 3 / TypeScript app that uses [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) and [Vue Concurrency](https://vue-concurrency.netlify.app/).

And I have been playing around to see if I can use Vue Concurrency *inside* Pinia.

This is what I have in Pinia at the moment:

```ts
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { User } from 'src/types';
import { useUpdateDocTask } from 'src/composables/database';
import { useTask } from 'vue-concurrency';

const updateDocTask = useUpdateDocTask();

export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      user: {} as User,
    };
  },
  actions: {
    setFirstNameTask() {
      return useTask(function* (signal, firstName: string) {
        this.user.firstName = firstName; // ERROR HERE
        yield updateDocTask.perform('users', this.user.uid, { // ERROR HERE
          firstName,
        });
      });
    },
});
```

But I am getting these TypeScript and Eslint errors on all instances of `this`:

```
this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation. ts(2683)

user.ts(38, 22): An outer value of 'this' is shadowed by this container.

Unsafe member access .user on an `any` value.eslint @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
```

Is it possible to overcome these errors?

How could this be done correctly?

Comment: [this value in JavaScript anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8670877/381282)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special case of [this common problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback), the problem is that generator function doesn't have arrow counterpart, and needs to be bound to correct `this`, and also typed correctly.

Considering that `useTask` doesn't provide specific functionality to bind callback context and infer `thisArg` type, it will work as:

```
  type This = typeof this;

  return useTask(function* (this: This, signal, firstName: string) {
    this.user...
    ...
  }.bind(this));
```

Or with old-fashioned `self = this` recipe:

```
  const state = this;
  return useTask(function* (signal, firstName: string) {
    state.user...
    ...
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but unfortunatley both solutions have a console error `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'useUserStore' before initialization`.

Comment: @TinyTiger You don't have any `useUserStore` anywhere in the code shown in the question. So the error you are mentioning is not in any way related to this question/answer and should not be used as an excuse to not accept this as an answer (because it **is** correct answer)

Comment: @TinyTiger The error means that there's `useUserStore()` above useUserStore declaration, and this needs to be avoided. As it was said, this isn't shown in the question and is a different problem that the solution isn't supposed to affect.

Comment: Ok thanks for explaining. Have accepted the answer and will try to debug this other problem separately.